# I want to delete specific line from text file, but my code don't work

Tags: c#, .net

```
int stv = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
StreamReader read = File.OpenText("Izdelki.txt");
int st = 1;
string newtext=" ";
string line = read.ReadLine();
while (line != null)
{
    st++;
    if (st != stv) 
    {
        newtext += line;
    }

}
```

**I think this should work, but I am not sure. I am doing this for scholl project. If you have some other sugestion please write it.**

Comment: Just compile and run it. If you encounter any error, post it.

Comment: There is no any errors, it just don't work.

Comment: @NihadSuljkanović Yes, that's because you never write anything into file, you only **read** it. Check `File.ReadAllLines()` and `File.WriteAllLines()` methods

Comment: You never get next line. I think that you should add line = read.ReadLine() at loop end

Comment: @Fabjan thank's. I don't know how I didn't see that?

Comment: check out the answers .. they might help

Answer (score 1):

Use LINQ, Luke!

```
int stv = ...

var lines = File.ReadAllLines("Izdelki.txt")
    .Where((s, i) => i != stv);

File.WriteAllLines("Izdelki.txt", lines);
```

Maybe you should use condition like this:

```
i != (stv - 1)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you're correct this code only *reads* from file without writing anything into it.

It's very useful to think of string file as an array or collection of `string`s.
It means that when file is read it puts everything into a string collection/array and write operation will simply write this array back to file.
For this you have two methods : `File.ReadAllLines()` and `File.WriteAllLines()`.

You can do something along the lines of:

```
int stv = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
List<string> file = File.ReadAllLines("Izdelki.txt").ToList();

// find index of line that you need to change here and change it in your List eg file[x] = y
// now save it using File.WriteAllLines("Izdelki.txt", file);
```

Comment: it doesn't remove any line ... :( and thts basically what the OP wants